# Can't transition slider text from one array object to another

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a Filter overlay, and I can't seem to get the array items to connect with my html slider. Essentially instead of viewing a number change values when the user selects and drags the slider, I want to output each of the values within the age_Slider array.

I can only seem to print out the value that I have in the span "ageRange" which is "No age limit".

I've tried several approaches stemming from w3schools:
[1] https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp
and from this site:
[2] http://webtutsdepot.com/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/

These sites have helped me to get this far, but I'm hoping someone wouldn't mind explaining the logic of what I would need, keeping in mind that I can't use any jQuery for this. If I can visualize and understand your logic I can try to figure out the rest.

Here's my code that I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>AGE SLIDER</h2>

<ul><strong>AGE:</strong> <span id="ageRange"> No age limit</span><br><br>
    <input id="ageSlider" type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" onchange="ageSliderValue(this.value)" name="ageSlider"></ul>
    <ul>No age limit/8+/10+/12+/13+/14+</ul>


<script>
var age_Slider = ["No age limit, 8+, 10+, 12+, 13+, 14+"];
function ageSliderValue(newValue) {
    document.getElementById("ageSlider").innerHTML = age_Slider;
    document.getElementById("ageRange").innerHTML = age_Slider;

   for(i = 0; i < age_Slider.length i++) {
        if (age_Slider == 0) {
            document.getElementById("ageRange").innerHTML= age_Slider[0];
            age_Slider[0];
        }
        else if(age_Slider == 1) {
         document.getElementById("ageRange").innerHTML= age_Slider[1];
         age_Slider[1];
        }
        else if(age_Slider == 2) {            
            document.getElementById("ageRange").innerHTML= age_Slider[2];
            age_Slider[2];
        }
        else if(age_Slider == 3) {            
            document.getElementById("ageRange").innerHTML= age_Slider[3];
            age_Slider[3];
        }
        else if(age_Slider == 4) {
            document.getElementById("ageRange").innerHTML= age_Slider[4];
            age_Slider[4];
        }
        else if(age_Slider == 5){
            document.getElementById("ageRange").innerHTML= age_Slider[5];
            age_Slider[5];
        }
        else {
            alert("Out of Bounds!");
        }
    }
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I messed up on a couple of things, first I didn't put "" around each item in my array, which was making it all just one item instead of 6 different items, second I didn't need to have the for loop at all, I just needed to test it with console logging the "newValue" and accessing the "newValue" from the array instead of the first item in the array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>AGE SLIDER</h2>
<section id="contentDiv"> </section>
<ul><strong>AGE:</strong> <span id="ageRange"> No age limit</span><br><br>
    <input id="ageSlider" type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" onchange="ageSliderValue(this.value)" name="ageSlider"></ul>
    <ul>No age limit/8+/10+/12+/13+/14+</ul>


<script>
var age_Slider = ["No age limit", "8+", "10+", "12+", "13+", "14+"];
function ageSliderValue(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    document.getElementById("ageRange").innerHTML = age_Slider[newValue];    
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```